# evenBitParity - returns 1 if an odd number of the even-indexed bits of x are 0's (bit 0 of x is the 1's place)

Tags: bit

The is a bit manipulation problem.

```
/*
evenBitParity - returns 1 if an odd number of the even-indexed bits of x are 0's (bit 0 of x is the 1's place)
  Examples:
    evenBitParity(0) = 0 (16 zero even-indexed bits),
    evenBitParity(2) = 0 (16 zero even-indexed bits, bit 1 is non-zero but not even-indexed)
    evenBitParity(3) = 1 (15 zero even-indexed bits),
    evenBitParity(5) = 0 (14 zero-indexed bits),
    evenBitParity(7) = 0
    evenbitParity(21) = 1
  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
  Max ops: 15
  Rating: 4
*/
int evenBitParity(int x) {

}
```

I try to solve it with the code below, but the operations are too many so I didn't get full credit. Can anyone give a better solution for this?
Thanks a lot!

```
int masker = (0x55 << 8)+0x55;
masker = (masker<<16)+masker;
x = x&masker;
x = x ^ (x >> 1);
x = x ^ (x >> 2);
x = x ^ (x >> 4);
x = x ^ (x >> 8);
x = x ^ (x >> 16);
return x&1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution:

```
int masker = (0x55 << 8)+0x55;
    y = (x >> 16) & masker;
    x = x&masker;
    x = x ^ y;
    x = x ^ (x >> 1);
    x = x ^ (x >> 2);
    x = x ^ (x >> 4);
    x = x ^ (x >> 8);
return x&1;
```

Comment: more details: https://blog.csdn.net/anlian523/article/details/84488468?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-BlogCommendFromMachineLearnPai2-2.add_param_isCf&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant.none-task-blog-BlogCommendFromMachineLearnPai2-2.add_param_isCf

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for your self. The improved version is ebp2();

You didn't need to use a mask and all that. Simply omit the first shift to ignore all odd-indexed bits.

I think I deserve a beer or at least a coffee for my effort.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int x;
    x = 0;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, ebp1(x), ebp2(x)); 
    x = 2;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, ebp1(x), ebp2(x)); 
    x = 3;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, ebp1(x), ebp2(x)); 
    x = 5;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, ebp1(x), ebp2(x)); 
    x = 7;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, ebp1(x), ebp2(x)); 
    x = 21;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, ebp1(x), ebp2(x)); 
}

int ebp1(int x){
    int masker = (0x55 << 8)+0x55;
    masker = (masker<<16)+masker;
    x = x&masker;
    x = x ^ (x >> 1);
    x = x ^ (x >> 2);
    x = x ^ (x >> 4);
    x = x ^ (x >> 8);
    x = x ^ (x >> 16);
    return x&1;
}

int ebp2(int x){
    x = x ^ (x >> 2);
    x = x ^ (x >> 4);
    x = x ^ (x >> 8);
    x = x ^ (x >> 16);
    return x&1;
}
```

Comment: The reader is invited to find an even better solution to this problem. Specifically, there might be one that avoids all that shift-accumulating with addition.

Comment: glad you think so. Though I know this prolly reached you waay too late for it to be useful...